# React updating state after component has been unmounted (memory leak)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm building a react app (am a noob at javascript) and struggling with react trying to update a state after the component has been unmounted.

Context for the react app: as part of a school project I have to build a movie ticket booking service for a small theatre complex, on the home page of the web app I have an image 'carousel' which is updating the image every 5 seconds.

Here is the home page in action: https://apollo-9dd16.web.app/

(the image loading time is just because I chose rather large images, will be fixed) - also the loading screen when first accessing the page is because it takes that long to load everything from firebase (everything is dynamically updated through firebase database) if there is a way to make it quicker please let me know

Also, I've gone through as many SO posts as I can find and everyone suggests adding a check if the component is mounted before performing state changes, which I think I've done?

Anyways, onto the problem, for some reason, it will come up saying I have a memory leak as I am trying to change the components state after it is unmounted (I can't reproduce it easily but it has happened a number of times)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import MoviesContext from '../contexts/Movies'


/* Todo: 

 - Work on the transition between movies
 - Work on sending the user to the right place on book now button press

*/

class Home extends Component {
    static contextType = MoviesContext
    state = {
        intervalID:0,
        index:1,
        prevIndex:0,
        nextIndex:2,
        picList:[]
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        let mounted = true
        const posterURLS = [] // eslint-disable-next-line
        this.context.map((movies) => {
            posterURLS.push(movies.posterURL)
        })
        this.setState({picList: posterURLS})

        if(mounted) {
            const newIntervalId = setInterval(() => {
                if (this.state.nextIndex + 1 === this.state.picList.length ){
                    this.setState({ 
                        prevIndex: this.state.index,
                        index: this.state.nextIndex,
                        nextIndex: 0
                    })
                } else {
                    this.setState({
                        prevIndex: this.state.index,
                        index: this.state.nextIndex,
                        nextIndex: this.state.nextIndex + 1
                    })
                }
            }, 5000);
        
        
            this.setState(prevState => {
                return {
                    ...prevState,
                    intervalId: newIntervalId,
                };
            });

        }
        return () => mounted = false
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="font-sans font-light text-theme-white text-4xl z-10 flex justify-center items-center h-screen">
                <div className="h-3/4">
                    <div className="h-full justify-center items-center">
                        <div className="h-full hidden md:flex">
                            <img src={this.state.picList[this.state.prevIndex]} alt="this is a movie" className="h-full rounded-2xl -mx-20"/>
                            <img src={this.state.picList[this.state.nextIndex]} alt="this is a movie" className="h-full rounded-2xl -mx-20"/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="absolute inset-10 flex justify-center items-center h-screen">
                            <img src={this.state.picList[this.state.index]} alt="this is a movie" className="h-3/4 rounded-2xl"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="absolute inset-0 top-10 flex justify-center items-center">
                        <Link to="/book" className="bg-theme-light text-theme-black rounded-2xl py-3 px-5 hover:bg-theme-black hover:text-theme-light">Book Now</Link>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>  
        )  
    }

}

export default Home
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close! The reason that this is happening is because of this code:

```
/* 1 */  if (mounted) {
/* 2 */    const newIntervalId = setInterval(() => {
/* 3 */      if (this.state.nextIndex + 1 === this.state.picList.length) {
/* 4 */        this.setState({
/* 5 */          prevIndex: this.state.index,
/* 6 */          index: this.state.nextIndex,
/* 7 */          nextIndex: 0,
/* 8 */        });
/* 9 */      } else {
/* 10 */        this.setState({
/* 11 */          prevIndex: this.state.index,
/* 12 */          index: this.state.nextIndex,
/* 13 */          nextIndex: this.state.nextIndex + 1,
/* 14 */        });
/* 15 */      }
/* 16 */    }, 5000);
/* 17 */  
/* 18 */    this.setState((prevState) => {
/* 19 */      return {
/* 20 */        ...prevState,
/* 21 */        intervalId: newIntervalId,
/* 22 */      };
/* 23 */    });
/* 24 */  }
/* 25 */
```

The `if (mounted)` condition on line 1 (in the above snippet) is up a bit too high. You should wrap the if statement around the `setState` calls on lines 4 and 10 as these are both inside the `setInterval` function callback.

Currently, the code is saying:

- If the component is mounted
- Register this interval which updates the state every 5 seconds

But what I believe you'd like your code to say:

- If the component is mounted
- Update the state every 5 seconds, **but only if the component is still mounted**

```
if (mounted) {
  const newIntervalId = setInterval(() => {
    if (this.state.nextIndex + 1 === this.state.picList.length) {
      if (mounted) {
        this.setState({
          prevIndex: this.state.index,
          index: this.state.nextIndex,
          nextIndex: 0,
        });
      }
    } else {
      if (mounted) {
        this.setState({
          prevIndex: this.state.index,
          index: this.state.nextIndex,
          nextIndex: this.state.nextIndex + 1,
        });
      }
    }
  }, 5000);

  this.setState((prevState) => {
    return {
      ...prevState,
      intervalId: newIntervalId,
    };
  });
}
```

That should fix the component update after the component is already unmounted. You might even be able to remove the `if (mounted)` check at the start of the above snippet.

The reason it's happening is that at the time the `componentDidMount` function is executed the `mounted` variable is `true`, so it'll register the `setInterval` callback and keeps executing it every 5 seconds.

While the `mounted` variable may no longer be `true` when the `setInterval` callback is executed, there's nothing stopping it from executing.

Comment: Thank you so much! I cant check it right away as I couldn't get it to happen reliably, however Ill update the code and hopefully it wont happen again :)

Comment: Also, will I need an if(mounted) around the last setState (the one changing the interval id?)

Comment: That won't be necessary because we know that at that time (when `componentDidMount` was called) the `setState` could be executed without any issues (the component just mounted, so we can safely update the state).